# Installed paper theme and top bar is white

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I have installed paper theme via git clone and for some reason the top bar is white, how do i resolve this?

I'm not sure why this is happening, but this happened after installing a theme, i noticed that every shell i activate, i get the same white top bar. (sometimes with black fades)

[image]

Comment: Colour of the top-bar is dictated by the shell theme, not the application theme (GTK+ theme). Try changing the shell theme in Tweaks. Also I think light background colour with dark text colour is standard in GNOME Classic session.

Comment: @pomsky i am logged into Gnome Ubuntu since i dont want the default ubuntu shell themes. when i change "shell" in the tweaks app i still get the top bar white. doesnt matter  which shell i use