# Using GNOME Paper theme: how do I make my dock appear when hovering on the left side of my screen?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-classic, ubuntu-dock, dock

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and GNOME (shell version 3.26.2) Paper theme (entering GNOME Classic in login screen).

How do I make my dock appear when hovering on the left side of my screen? It's displayed only when pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> button (dock options on settings menu doesn't exist in GNOME Shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Dock is not supposed to be a part of GNOME Classic. The "dock" you see after pressing <kbd>super</kbd> is the GNOME dash (which is converted to a dock by "Dash to Dock" and "Ubuntu Dock").

You may try one of the following:

1. Switch to a default "GNOME" or "Ubuntu" session (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/966470/480481)).
2. Install and activate the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension.

Comment: can you please help me with the other (top) bar? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011374/installed-paper-theme-and-top-bar-is-white